# Bluetooth Device Shows Up In Menu But Not In Preferences

Tags: bluetooth, preferences, ios

I have an issue where an old iPhone I no longer own shows up in the Bluetooth menu but not in the bluetooth preferences. Screenshots below. Anyone else experiencing this? How to go about removing the item "iPhone-FFFV" below?

[image: iPhone-FFFV in menu.]
[image: No option to remove iPhone-FFFV in preferences.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had this same issue (device shows up in Bluetooth menu bar but not in System Preferences pane) on OS X 10.10.1 after replacing my iPhone, but I found another way to remove the old device, without editing or deleting the plist file.

Many system menu bar icons support advanced menus if you hold the Option key when you click them (for example, choosing an AirPlay device under audio, or seeing wifi modes and noise for your current network).  When **holding Option and clicking the Bluetooth icon**, there is extra information including my bluetooth hardware address, a "Create Diagnostics Report on the Desktop" item—and each device's submenu has its hardware address, signal strength, **and a Remove button**.  Worked great, no reboot required!

Comment: This is a much better solution. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Deleting /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist and rebooting worked.

Comment: I am having the same issue trying to connect a PS3 DualShock controller to a new rMBP in Yosemite and this did not solve the problem.

Comment: @mikegreiling My issue was not with trying to connect something via bluetooth, it was with trying to remove an old device from the menu that I no longer used.

Comment: Ah, my issue is similar in that the lists in the menu and the Bluetooth prefpane do not match. I was hoping this trick would help.

Comment: The solution proposed by @emsearcy did not work for me... although it probably should have worked since Apple provided the "Remove" menu item with a clear intention of removing a device.  Since this is some kind of bug in the underlying system it seems not all solutions will work for all cases.  In my case, deleting the plist file worked.

Comment: @Jason Good to know. At least we have two solutions here to work with.